# Flutter web responsive design font

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I'm trying to develop responsive  design for flutter web.

I'm not sure which I should use fontSize or textScaleFactor.

Is there any suggestion?

Thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked [TextTheme Class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextTheme-class.html) and [Type Scale](https://material.io/design/typography/the-type-system.html#), they have declared default size for all purposes.
[image]